# Adding Java ME platform in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, java-me, platform

I installed NetBeans 7.2.1 with JDK 7 and the plug-in - Java ME SDK 3.2 (it has Wireles Toolkit 2.5.2 inside).

I try to create new project by clicking **File/New Project/Java ME/Mobile Application**. Then I click **next**. In next window the message:

> Every CLDC project needs to have CLDC compatible SDK/platform/emulator assigned to it.

Pressing **Install SDK/Platform/Emulator** button opens Platform Installation wizard, which allows you to "add platform".

[image]

I tried clicking **Install SDK/Platform/Emulator** button and I tried then indicating the folder, where Java ME 3.2 is installed. It can recognize the emulator, but the project cannot be started.

[image]

After the choice, there appear several options. How to make in new version? Most of the thing in Internet are connected to old version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I configured it. I had plug-in without SDK:). I uninstalled plug-in. I installed Java ME SDK 3.2, then I installed plug-in. I installed SDK not in the default path. I indicated platform using "Add platform" button. I indicated 2 platforms and now the project can be run in the emulator.

Here are platforms:):
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried [using this Oracle tutorial online](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamesdk/entry/how_to_integrate_java_me1)?  It's fairly current (September 2012).  There's also an even newer one [just posted here](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamesdk/entry/installing_java_me_sdk_plugin).

If you install the Java ME SDK that way, you should have the proper **Java Platforms** there already.  It's hard to read your screen capture, but it doesn't look like the proper Java Platforms are there.  I would try again, following the steps in the link I provided.

I just tried it, with NetBeans 7.2.1, and the Java ME SDK 3.2.  The version of NetBeans I used was from [this download page](http://netbeans.org/downloads/) and was the **Java EE** version.

One easy thing to miss in the steps below is that on [this download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/sdk/index.html), you need to download **both** the Java ME SDK **and** the Java ME SDK Plugin for Netbeans.  Not just the plugin.  This applies for the installation instructions in either of the two links I posted above.  **Install the SDK**, and not just the plugin.

---

In case that link later changes/dies, here are the important steps:

### How to integrate Java ME SDK 3.2 with NetBeans

By SungmoonCho on Sep 25, 2012

Many people like to use Java ME SDK with IDEs. We provided instructions on how to integrate the SDK with NetBeans through the download page, and also through the release note, however, let me explain it here once again with some screen shots.

1. Download Java ME SDK **and** NetBeans plugin from here.
2. Install Java ME SDK first. You will have the emulator and the runtime on your machine. Also please unarchive the NetBeans plugin somewhere.
3. Launch NetBeans.
4. Go to "Tools" - "Plugins".
5. Check out the "Installed" tab. Check "Show details". If you see the previous version of Java ME SDK Tools installed already. Check those to uninstall them.
6. Go to "Settings" tab.
7. Click "Add", and provide the location of NetBeans plugin. In my case, it is "file:/C:/Users/sungcho/Downloads/nb-me-sdk-plugins-uc/updates.xml". Don't forget to add "updates.xml" at the end.
8. Click "Okay"
9. Click "Available Plugins" tab.
10. If you scroll down, you will see three Java ME SDK Tools. Check "Java ME SDK Tools" plugin. Also check others as you desire.
11. Follow the instruction and install them.
12. Restart NetBeans
13. That is it. Done. Now you will see Oracle Java ME SDK 3.2 in your Java Platform list.

Comment: I did like here [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamesdk/entry/installing_java_me_sdk_plugin).

Comment: Good.  But take special note of my comment about installing the **SDK** and also the **plugin**.  Not just the plugin.