# Not able to open already created Java ME project in NetBeans

Tags: java, java-me

I was using the NetBeans IDE 7.3, however on open an existing mobility project I get lots of red dots,

on rolling over the dot near the package statement it says

```
'cannot access java.lang"
Fatal Error:" Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath"
```

while the other red dots below near other class or Identifier statements say

"cannot find symbol."

I have JDK 1.7.0_11 installed.

I tried the following to correct the errors:

```
1. Reinstalled JDK 1.7 .
2. Reinstalled NetBeans 7.3.
3. Uninstalled NetBeans 7.3 and installed NetBeans 7.3
```

However nothing worked.

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.3 (Build 201302132200)
Updates: Updates available
Java: 1.7.0_11; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 23.6-b04
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_11-b21
System: Windows Vista version 6.0 running on x86; Cp1252; en_US (nb)
User directory: C:\Users\SSNEHAL\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.3
Cache directory: C:\Users\SSNEHAL\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\7.3
```

I also searched google but could not find any valid answers.
What should I do?

Interestingly I get these errors only on Mobility projects and that too on opening an existing Mobility project,
New Mobility and J2SE projects dont give me any errors.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127373/adding-java-me-platform-in-netbeans

Comment: I already install all the required plugins but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If new projects work, Netbeans probably lost the platform configuration for your project (this happened to me once). To reconfigure it go to Project Properties -> Platform and set the Platform Type and Emulator to your JavaME platform.